# C# Regular Expression Replace and Add to End

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a find/replace regular expression in C# to find strings that start with -i, then contain any number of digits (no spaces) and then replace the -i with an empty string, but also add 2 spaces to the end to make up for removing the -i (it is a fix length file).

Right now, I am doing this to replace the text without adding the spaces at the end:

```
File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text), @"[-i]", ""));
```

An example line in the file is:

```
-i3598            00015
```

And I want the result to be:

```
3598              00015
```

Notice that the total length is the same before and after.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following.  It uses [Regular Expressions Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) in the replacement pattern.

```
File.WriteAllText(
    textBox1.Text, 
    Regex.Replace(
        File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text), 
        @"-i(\d+)", 
        "$1  "));
```